# Do I have to repeat my prayer If stood slightly behind imam when praying alone with him?

Tags: salat

During COVID, if one leads another in prayer, and there are only two people praying I found that both should stand on exactly the same line, neither slightly behind nor slightly ahead.

But what if one didn't know about this and the muqtadi stood slightly behind their family member who is leading the prayer, does he have to repeat his prayer?

Pardon my English, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: You should clarify did you pray like this due to ignorance, due to fear and precaution (covid) or what was the reason?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Due to ignorance, I didn't know about this ruling.

Comment: and the imam how about him?

Comment: @Medi1Saif He didn't know as well as he is not a proper imam, he was just leading the prayer at home.